# How to change in mysql datatype float dot to comma?

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql database I have a column with `float` datatype and with length 10,2.
When I put the data in database in row it looks like this:

> 2,589.20

In my country, Serbia, visually will need to look like this:

> 2.589,20
>
> (first dots, then comma).

When I use it in "value" of form (input) the `number_format($number, 2, '.', ',')` then I can put the `$number` in the database, but if it's a `number_format($faktura_cenanasa, 2, ',', '.')` in "value" then I can't put it in database because of a wrong format of the "value". This problem is only when I reload the data in form, when a reload it somewhere else on site it't not a problem (when I print it on screen).

Comment: Don't change your database structure, or else MySQL won't be able to use it as necessary. You can change how it outputs with [FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format). For inputting, you'll need to use a standard format, which does not use commas (123467.32)

Comment: Or if you use php, then format the number when you print it out via php. MySQL does not store the data in a formatted way, every formatting is the responsibility of the application that displays the data.

Answer (score 1):

number_format due to rounding can return misleading output especially for large numbers.

for instance

```
echo number_format( 1000000000000000000.00952, 2 );
// output: 1,000,000,000,000,000,000.00
echo number_format( 9999999999999999999.00952, 2 );
// output: 10,000,000,000,000,000,000.00
echo number_format( 999999999999999999999999999.00952, 2 );
// output: 1,000,000,000,000,000,013,287,555,072.00
```

Alternatively like @aynber wrote in a comment you should add one more aliased column or replace the number column with `FORMAT` in your query

```
SELECT ..., FORMAT( `number`, 2, 'de_DE' ) AS `formatted_number`
  FROM ...
```

Before replacing the locale to Serbian (in the example is 'de_DE') you should check that it is available into [Mysql Locale Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html)

Additionally just in case make sure that the formatted output is what you expect. There might be a case where your result will be something like the following, instead both should have the same format.

```
SELECT FORMAT(12500000000000.2015, 2,'de_DE'), FORMAT(12500000000000.2015, 2,'el_GR');
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| FORMAT(12500000000000.2015, 2,'de_DE') | FORMAT(12500000000000.2015, 2,'el_GR') |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| 12.500.000.000.000,20                  | 12500000000000,20                      |
+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

**update**

When you receive the number formatted- well not a number anymore instead a string- you will be able to edit it as you are please. But, before storing it back to the database you will need to remove all thousand separators and then change the decimal point to '.', i.e

```
$number = str_replace( [ '.', ',' ], ['', '.'], $number );
```

Finally insert and this is it.